Preserve inner shadow in container
I am working on a react project with Tailwind CSS where I have a div (with inner shadow) block acting a as a container to a scroll-able page. The page has elements that stick to the top upon scroll. This affects the inner shadow of the container. I can't really change the position of the sticky elements as I want the scroll-able elements slowly fade away. I have pasted the snippets below. Thanks in advance.
Container div block:
<div className="mb-10 h-11/12 w-11/12 rounded-lg bg-white border shadow-inner-dark overflow-y-scroll">
Sticky block:
      <div className="sticky top-0 mb-6 h-40 w-full flex flex-col items-center">
        <div className="bg-white min-w-full text-center">
          <h1 className="text-4xl text-black font-silkscreen">Agent Hub </h1>
        </div>
        <div className="w-full grid place-items-center backdrop-blur-xl">
          <div className="w-full grid place-items-center  bg-gradient-to-t from-transparent to-white">
            <input
              type="text"
              className="mt-10 w-1/4 pl-6 py-2 rounded-full bg-black opacity-80 hover:shadow-2xl-dark text-white placeholder-gray-500 focus:outline-none transition duration:700"
              placeholder="Search..."
              value={searchTerm}
              onChange={(e) => setSearchTerm(e.target.value)}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

I tried meddling with the z-index but it wasn't of much use.
Edit: I’ve added my tailwind config and input.css below.
theme: {
    extend: {
      fontFamily: {
        'silkscreen': 'Silkscreen',
      },
      boxShadow: {
        'inner-dark': 'inset 0 4px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)',
        '2xl-dark': '0 25px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15)',
      },
    },
  },

@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer utilities {
    .scrollbar-hide::-webkit-scrollbar {
      display: none;
    }
    .scrollbar-hide {
      -ms-overflow-style: none;
      scrollbar-width: none;
    }
  }


It seems you have used some classes which aren't included in Tailwind by default. Could you please provide your Tailwind configuration and input CSS please?

@Wongjn Thanks for replying. I have just added my config. I haven’t got input.css, but I have included my index.css.
